# Is QFileInfo synchronized with file?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Is `QFileInfo` synchronized with source file? Or it just stores information from the time when the instance was created?

In otherwords, if I create `QFileInfo` instance for my file. Then I change the file. And then, I create second instance of `QFileInfo` for this file, will they have different lastModified value?

Comment: Just try this. I guess that it is not synchronized.

Comment: It's not synchronized, in particular see `QFileInfo::refresh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QFileInfo is not syncronized, the information is read when the object is created.

I have used this small example to verify it.

If you run this in a terminal and then change the file you will see the date changing when you save the file.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QThread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    while (1)
    {
        QFileInfo f("./file.txt");
        qDebug() << f.lastModified().toString();
        QThread::sleep ( 1 );
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Won't this example block the event loop so that user cannot interact with the program?

Comment: Probably yes vahancho, but as you can see there is no user interface so not much to interact with anyway :-)